# Serial downvote reversal bot possibly missed some downvotes

Tags: support, downvotes, serial-voting

Yesterday I was serially downvoted on 40 of my questions and answers so I lost 80 points - I must have really pee'd someone off. The serial voting bot ran last night and caught the majority, however it only gave me 72 points back.

I can't see from the report which questions and answers had votes removed to tally up exactly which were missed.

Can anyone tell me if these additional 4 downvotes are just a coincidence and came from other users, or something the bot missed?

Comment: I don't know whether moderators can see this, but it's likely wise to just let it go (even though I know malicious downvotes suck, and feel like an undeserved blemish).

Comment: @Pekka웃 I agree, I was more wondering if there was an issue in the bot's algorithm. Personally I think the guy who did it deserves a badge. Took him over 30 mins work. That's some serious effort. Silver for definite :D

Comment: actually it took him/her 13 mins  9:06 to 9:19

Comment: Ah yes, so it did. Ok, bronze then

Comment: How do you know it wasn't 36 serial votes and four non-serial?

Comment: A DV, the first in 3 years, on an answer with 70 UpVotes the same minute as three other DVs on a user with a gold badge in the subject seems...unlikely to be unrelated.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't, that's why I'm asking for confirmation. It just seemed odd that I'd get 4 unrelated downvotes on old answers in a single day. I normally get a few every week or so, and it just seemed too much of a coincidence as I'd had a lot of targeted downvotes the same day.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan even mods can't see who voted, only developers: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90735/248731. It does seem unlikely to be coincidental, though.

Comment: I've noticed before that it can miss stuff looking at [this user's reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1525840/konrad-viltersten?tab=reputation) for May 21st it looks like they had two batches of serial downvoting and only the smaller one was cleaned up.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I already had a similar situation, where I had the feeling, that the bot missed one or two downvotes to reverse. But I had also several upV's and there it even reversed too much :) So at the end I lost like 20 points. I think at the end just leave it, you will get to your 100k  :)

Comment: There's been several cases where I suspect a user to downvote some answers of mine purely out of spite (I mean, what's the chance of getting into an argument with someone and then 3 downvotes on years old answers within minutes/hours of each other where I rarely take 1 downvote per week?); each time though, it's made me smirk, because the penalty for downvoting the downvoter got is likely to be (comparatively) more important that the penalty I got for being downvoted.

Comment: Personally I think every downvoter should be held accountable and at least be required to provide a reason. The main benefits would be it actually teaches people to format questions and secondly it helps weed out those who are quite simply a-holes.

Comment: @MrkFldig only if upvoting an existing comment counts as providing a reason.

Comment: I think that I just recently [pissed somebody off](http://i.imgur.com/iN8lTVY.jpg). Let's see if the serial-vote robot finds this nifty collection. :)

Comment: @Rizier123 He is at 111k already.

Comment: @tripleee I wasn't when he commented ;)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Moderators can't see who voted for your posts, only larger suspicious trends, so I can't determine if those were from the same user. It's likely, but I can't be sure.

The serial voting invalidation process is conservative by design, to try to avoid too many false positives. They keep tweaking it, but I have noticed that it can often miss a handful of votes at the beginning or end of a streak. The ones that weren't invalidated here came a half hour or so apart from the others (which all came within a span of minutes). It is possible they were from another user or users, but I personally think that's unlikely.

The only thing moderators could do in a case like this is to call in an SE employee to manually verify and invalidate votes in the database, but they're pretty busy. We try to only bring them in on much larger voting patterns or voting rings. If you feel this is bad enough to warrant manual intervention, you could flag one of your posts and we might pass it along to the SE team.

Comment: IMO a dev should look at this as it would be a bug that needs fixing. Invalidating 36/40 serial downvotes from the same user would not be correct behaviour if that is indeed what happened. IMO in cases of serial downvoting all votes in the batch should be regarded as invalid.

Comment: Or, a much more colorful solution, all reputation changes that are reversed  by the bot could be translated into reputation loss for the serial voter. I doubt you would do that twice.

Comment: The history that *we* can see shows all of them in a 13 mins window - there are small gaps at 9:12-13 and 9:15 where the voter slowed down.  Seems like it ought to be able to connect the 2-3 series into one and/or loosen up the criteria once a series of X DVs in whatever timeframe.

Comment: @Plutonix: FWIW, the script does adapt once it catches someone: it becomes increasingly willing to consider their votes serial. Not sure it does so in time to broaden the first catch, though.

Answer (score 22):

This is pretty surely a bug in the reversal script. Same thing happened to me (but I forgot to report it).

On June 15:
[image: Five downvotes in my log]
which clearly was serial downvoting on my five highest-scoring questions. I was sure the detection would trigger on them, so I waited for the reversal. But on the next day:
[image: reversal action for 8 points]
only four downvotes were corrected.

Comment: Same happened to me.on may 30,someone downvoted all of my question.4 was downvoted at same time and one was downvoted after 30min.May be thats the reason that script cannot detect.so it corrected 4.Even it cannot detect if serial vote count is 2.which is happened to me at june 13 and 21.

Comment: This is possibly a flaw in the way the algorithm is designed; e.g. i's not "serial" downvoting until the 2nd or 3rd vote, so the first (and/or second) vote don't need to be reversed?

Comment: Apparently getting involved in a debate attracts such behavior from people that are less capable to sustain stress and general butthurt (lacking other words to describe). Reversal helps, but it might be better to carry that scar than to be cleanse entirely - you're now an honorable Internet warrior. :)

Comment: @TylerH: Hm, usually the intention is malicious from the very beginning of a series. I'd guess that serial downvoting is mostly triggered by an independent dispute, not based on the first vote.

Comment: @Vesper: Yeah, sure, it's not exactly as if I desperately needed those 2 reputation points :-)

Answer (score -5):

Brad has the correct answer. As much as you may not like it, users are allowed
to downvote you if they feel your post is not useful. It only becomes a problem
if they are targeting users rather than posts.

The task then becomes determining which votes were targeting users and which
votes were targeting posts. This is impossible to get perfect because even the
person voting may not know with certainty why they are voting a certain way.

Take the example in your question. Even if all 40 of the downvotes were by the
same person, and even if they were targeting you, that doesnt mean that they can
never downvote you again. So the point of the algorithm is to draw that line
between when that person is "legally" and "illegally" downvoting you. Again as
I have said this is imperfect, they could decide to downvote you once a week and
get away with it, as long as they do not hit whatever threshold has been
programmed in. With enough time between votes it is impossible to know if they
are legitimate without reading the persons mind, and maybe not even then.

Comment: I... don't understand why this has so many downvotes.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus people dont want to consider the fact that they may just be wrong, or that their answer just may not be that good. It is much easier to just blame it on the people downvoting them

Comment: I downvoted because it is irrelevant. `Even if all 40 of the downvotes were by the same person, and even if they were targeting you, that doesnt mean that they can never downvote you again.` - Nobody is arguing that - but all 40 of them in that serial batch should be reversed.

Comment: @MartinSmith the point I think Steven was trying to make is that it's a fuzzy problem, and very difficult to define exactly what is serial downvoting. That means any algorithm is going to have a finite error rate, which is unfortunate, but not that avoidable.